# Shipping Methods empty?

Tags: sylius

I have set two shipping method that use flatrate (using CATEGORY_REQUIREMENT_MATCH_ANY) and checked the code in MethodsResolver->getSupportedMethods and it returns the two shipping methods. I just can't see them in the frontend at http://sylius.dev/app_dev.php/checkout/shipping and don't know whats wrong.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest it would be one of these:

#### shipping methods are not enabled in your channel

- check in your administration channel settings `administration/channels`
- see if you have chosen shipping method for your web/frontend chanel.
  [image]

#### shipping methods have zone restrictions

- check in you shipping method configuration, if you don't have it allowed only for specific county/zone
- also check if you don't have shipping category set with for those methods.

#### products have zone or shipping category restriction

- check if product(s) that you have added, are not restricted by zone or shipping category
- this can be set on editation of each product in administration.

#### try if same happens with demo.sylius.org

- can you replicate the same behaviour on the demo page ?

Comment: > shipping methods are not enabled in your channel

Can't see i can set channel on shipping method.

> shipping methods have zone restrictions
Have checked and they looked fine.
> products have zone or shipping category restriction
I have no restriction on the product (left empty on purpose) but i have also testede the product the the same zone and its still same result.
> try if same happens with demo.sylius.org
The demo page has the same error.

Comment: @YingopenconceptHo - you enable shipping method ON channel (in channel configuration), not the other way around .. I added a screenshot from demo.sylius.org for that part.